# Inserting data into a table and then reading that data and inserting it into another table

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a php form and on submit, I want the data to be sent to a table. After a successful entry, I then want to add up all the values (numerical) from a column  that share the same email address in the first column (the value is the 3rd column) and then submit that total to a different table. Is this even possible? I am using MySQL and PHP.

For example:

EMAIL(COL1)                    COL2              COL3

email@email.com       (data)                 10

email@email.com       (data)                 10

email@email.com       (data)                 10

COL3 TOTAL: 30

Submit 30 into new table with email address from COL1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider adding a trigger to your MySQL database. A trigger is a named database object that is associated with a table, and that activates when a particular event occurs for the table.

Comment: Interesting, I am not too versed in triggers. Is that something you need to have written in the form submit or does that script reside elsewhere?

Comment: You would first need to connect to your mySQL database, then run the create trigger command (CREATE TRIGGER). See this link for syntax and example:


https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: You also have to make sure the version of MySQL you're using supports triggers @Holodout A stored procedure would also be a viable option for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would just make a VIEW.

CREATE VIEW `total` AS SELECT `email`, SUM(`col3`) FROM `table` GROUP BY 1.

You could do this with triggers in MySQL or via PHP, but for this sort of simple operation a VIEW is probably most reliable and easiest.